# sql query applying multiple filters to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am inexperienced in SQL, need a query applying multi-layer filters to multiple tables for comparison purposes.

Table1:

Order_Number    Step_Name   Data    Parameter_Name
12  step4   const1  P1
12  step4   const2  P2
12  step4   value1  P3
30  step6   const3  P1
30  step6   const4  P2
30  step6   value2  P3

All tables have same format, only different in data values.
Order numbers might be different from table to table.

I want to do:

1. Search rows between Step_Name=step1 and step8 only
2. Find Order_Number matching (P1=const1 and P2=const2)
3. Save P3 rows in the same order number group.
4. Display all the rows (one from each table):

Order_Number    Table   Data    Parameter_Name
12  table1  value1  P3
12  table2  value2  P3
14  table3  value3  P3

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean with 'multi-layer filters' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add as many `union all...select` parts as necessary:

```
select
    order_number,
    'table1' as `table`,
    data,
    prameter_name
from
    table1 t1p3
where
    step_name in ('step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5', 'step6', 'step7', 'step8') and
    parameter = 'p3' and
    exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            table1 t1p1
        where
            t1p1.order_number = t1p3.order_number and
            t1p1.step_name = t1p3.step_name and
            t1p1.parameter = 'p1' and
            t1p1.data = 'const1'
    ) and exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            table1 t1p2
        where
            t1p2.order_number = t1p3.order_number and
            t1p2.step_name = t1p3.step_name and
            t1p2.parameter = 'p2' and
            t1p2.data = 'const2'
    ) 
union all
select
    order_number,
    'table2',
    data,
    prameter_name
from
    table2 t2p3
where
    step_name in ('step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5', 'step6', 'step7', 'step8') and
    parameter = 'p3' and
    exists (
        select
              'x'
        from
            table2 t2p1
        where
            t2p1.order_number = t2p3.order_number and
            t2p1.step_name = t2p3.step_name and
            t2p1.parameter = 'p1' and
            t2p1.data = 'const1'
    ) and exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            table2 t2p2
        where
            t2p2.order_number = t2p3.order_number and
            t2p2.step_name = t2p3.step_name and
            t2p2.parameter = 'p2' and
            t2p2.data = 'const2'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I followed your steps, and had success in a smaller scale of finding order_number with P1 and P2 at specific values.